# PHP ROUND Decimal integer

Tags: php

i'm having problem about, how to turn

**3.66666667** into **3.7**

what kind of php function that will help this problem out?

Comment: you could do that with round : round("3.66666667",1) http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: Did you TRY and google? I know for a fact that it's fairly easy to find if you try, I did it myself earlier. `number_format((float)3.66666667, 1, '.', '')` - because I'm a nice guy.

Comment: Use round() and you can learn about it from here http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_math_round.asp

Comment: Why spend 3 minutes to ask something you can google in 10 secs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
echo round( 3.66666667 , 1);
```

Comment: wow! its working! thank you so much Mr. Harish Lalwani!! You da real men!

Comment: your welcome @ChingChing

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo round( 3.66666667 , 1); ?>
```

Comment: No need to answer the same thing as an already existing answer.